# How to retrieve data from dynamically created table in html using python cgi

Tags: javascript, python, cgi

I am creating a table dynamically using javascript. Each row in table have one text box and i am giving name to text box like, sr.setAttribute("name", "box" + currentIndex); and incrementig after each call, so it will have a unique name, also i have button which can insert a row in b/w rows.

So, say text box are created in below sequence

Box1
Box2
Box4  (Box4 is before Box3, bacause this row is inserted after addition of row3)
Box3

Now these box values i am reading from python cgi scripting

```
data = cgi.FieldStorage()
for num in range(1,1000):
    a = data.getvalue( 'box{0}'.format(num))
    if a==None:
            pass
    else :
            f.write(a +'\n')

f.close()
```

So it is writing in file in sequence Box1, Box2, Box3, Box4 but actual sequence was Box1,Box2,Box4,Box3

Please help me how i can save box values in same sequence as it was present in table.